# Dynamic NG-Controller Name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to dynamically specify a controller based on a config that we load. Something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="{{config.controllerNameString}}>
    ...
</div>
```

How do I do this in angular? I thought this would be very easy, but I can seem to find a way of doing this.

Comment: Is there a parent controller or is this the top most controller?

Comment: numerous ways to load templates based on conditions and have controller set in templates

Comment: This would have a parent controller.

Comment: It would be best if this was config based, not template based. I do not wish to add ng-controllers to all of the templates if the controller name is in the config.

Comment: can also set controller in routeProvider

Answer (score 34, accepted):

What you want to do is have another directive run before anything else is called, get the controller name from some model remove the new directive and add the `ng-controller` directive, then re-compile the element.

That looks like this:

```
global.directive('dynamicCtrl', ['$compile', '$parse',function($compile, $parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    terminal: true,
    priority: 100000,
    link: function(scope, elem) {
      var name = $parse(elem.attr('dynamic-ctrl'))(scope);
      elem.removeAttr('dynamic-ctrl');
      elem.attr('ng-controller', name);
      $compile(elem)(scope);
    }
  };
}]);
```

Then you could use it in your template, like so:

```
<div dynamic-ctrl="'blankCtrl'">{{tyler}}</div>
```

with a controller like this:

```
global.controller('blankCtrl',['$scope',function(tyler){
    tyler.tyler = 'tyler';
    tyler.tyler = 'chameleon';
}]);
```

There's probably a way of interpolating the value (`$interpolate`) of the `dynamic-ctrl` instead of parsing it (`$parse`), but I couldn't get it to work for some reason.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. In my case I wanted to be passing a $scope variable instead of a string. So I just needed to do  dynamic-ctrl="myScopeVariable"

Comment: Nide solution. However, I suggest a priority of 550 instead of 100000. This way, the directive is executed before ng-controller (priority 600) but AFTER ng-if (priority 600). Otherwise you controller get initialized (during the call to $compile(elem)(scope)) even if the element is not on the page (if ng-if is false). Also, you can access to element's attributes using 'attrs' parameter of link function to handle camel casing (ie: attrs.dynamicCtrl).

Answer (score 5):

I'm using it in ng-repeat, so this is improved code for loops and sub objects:

Template:

```
<div class="col-xs6 col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3" ng-repeat="box in boxes">
<div ng-include src="'/assets/js/view/box_campaign.html'" ng-dynamic-controller="box.type"></div>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
mainApp.directive('ngDynamicController', ['$compile', '$parse',function($compile, $parse) {
  return {
      scope: {
          name: '=ngDynamicController'
      },
      restrict: 'A',
      terminal: true,
      priority: 100000,
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          elem.attr('ng-controller', scope.name);
          elem.removeAttr('ng-dynamic-controller');

          $compile(elem)(scope);
      }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: add :if (scope.src) elem.attr('src', "'"+scope.src+"'"); to support ng-include

Comment: You're including the `$parse` factory but you aren't using it.

Comment: what is the place to put:
if (scope.src) elem.attr('src', "'"+scope.src+"'"); ?

Answer (score 3):

Personally the 2 current solutions here didn't work for me, as the name of the controller would not be known when first compiling the element but later on during another digest cycle. Therefore I ended up using:

```
myapp.directive('dynamicController', ['$controller', function($controller) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      attrs.$observe('dynamicController', function(name) {
        if (name) {
          elem.data('$Controller', $controller(name, {
            $scope: scope,
            $element: elem,
            $attrs: attrs
          }));
        }
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```