# AngularJs Directive with dynamic Controller and template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to create a directive that has dynamic view with dynamic controller. the controller and the template view is coming from the server.

**The Directive**

```
var DirectivesModule = angular.module('BPM.Directives', []);
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('BPM.Directives')
        .directive('bpmCompletedTask', bpmCompletedTask);

    bpmCompletedTask.$inject = ['$window'];

    function bpmCompletedTask ($window) {
        // Usage:
        //     <bpmCompletedTask></bpmCompletedTask>
        // Creates:
        // 
        var directive = {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                type: '=',
                taskdata: '=',
                controllername:'@'
            },
            template: '<div ng-include="getContentUrl()"></div>',
            controller: '@',
            name: 'controllername'
            };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.getContentUrl = function () {
                return '/app/views/TasksViews/' + scope.type + '.html';
            }
            scope.getControllerName = function ()
            {
                console.warn("Controller Name is " + scope.type);
                return scope.type;
            }
        }
    }

})();
```

Here how I'm trying to use the directive

```
<div ng-controller="WorkflowHistoryController as vm">
    <h2>Workflow History</h2>
    <h3>{{Id}}</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="workflowStep in CompletedWorkflowSteps">
        <bpm-completed-task controllername="workflowStep.WorkflowTaskType.DataMessageViewViewName" taskdata="workflowStep.WorkflowTaskOutcome.TaskOutcome" type="workflowStep.WorkflowTaskType.DataMessageViewViewName">
        </bpm-completed-task>
    </div>    
</div>
```

The problem now is when the directive gets the controller name it get it as literal string not as a parameter.

Is it doable ?
if it's not doable, What is the best solution to create dynamic views with its controllers and display them dynamically inside ng-repeat?

Thanks,

**Update 20 Jan** I just updated my code in case if some one interested in it. All the Credit goes to @Meligy.

**The First Directive:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('BPM.Directives')
        .directive('bpmCompletedTask', bpmCompletedTask);

    bpmCompletedTask.$inject = ['$compile', '$parse'];

    function bpmCompletedTask ($compile, $parse) {
        var directive = {
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                console.warn('in the first directive - before if');
                if (!elem.attr('bpm-completed-task-inner'))
                {
                    console.warn('in the first directive');
                    var name = $parse(elem.attr('controllername'))(scope);
                    console.warn('Controller Name : ' + name);
                    elem = elem.removeAttr('bpm-completed-task');
                    elem.attr('controllernameinner', name);
                    elem.attr('bpm-completed-task-inner', '');
                    $compile(elem)(scope);
                }
            },
            restrict: 'A',
            };
        return directive;        
    }

})();
```

**The Second Directive**

```
angular
.module('BPM.Directives')
.directive('bpmCompletedTaskInner',['$compile', '$parse',
function ($window, $compile, $parse) {
    console.warn('in the second directive');
    return {
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.warn('in the second directive');
            scope.getContentUrl = function () {
                return '/app/views/TasksViews/' + scope.type + '.html';
            }
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            type: '=',
            taskdata: '=',
            controllernameinner: '@'
        },
        template: '<div ng-include="getContentUrl()"></div>',
        controller: '@',
        name: 'controllernameinner'
    };

}]);
```

**The Html**

```
 <div ng-repeat="workflowStep in CompletedWorkflowSteps">
        <div bpm-completed-task controllername="workflowStep.WorkflowTaskType.DataMessageViewViewName" taskdata="workflowStep.WorkflowTaskOutcome.TaskOutcome"
                            type="workflowStep.WorkflowTaskType.DataMessageViewViewName">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

I got it working, but it's really ugly. Check:

http://jsfiddle.net/p6Hb4/13/

Your example has a lot of moving pieces, so this one is simple, but does what you want.

Basically you need a wrapper directive that takes the JS object and converts into a string property, then you can use هى your directive for everything else (template, scope, etc).

.

**Update 2:**

Code Inline:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []).
directive('communicatorInner', ["$parse", "$compile",
  function($parse, $compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: "<input type='text' ng-model='message'/><input type='button' value='Send Message' ng-click='sendMsg()'><br/>",
      scope: {
        message: '='
      },
      controller: '@'
    };
  }
]).
directive('communicator', ['$compile', '$parse',
  function($compile, $parse) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope, elem) {
        if (!elem.attr('communicator-inner')) {
          var name = $parse(elem.attr('controller-name'))(scope);
          elem = elem.removeAttr('controller-name')
          elem.attr('communicator-inner', name);
          $compile(elem)(scope);
        }
      }
    };
  }
]).
controller("PhoneCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.sendMsg = function() {
    alert($scope.message + " : sending message via Phone Ctrl");
  }
}).
controller("LandlineCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.sendMsg = function() {
    alert($scope.message + " : sending message via Land Line Ctrl ");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-init="test = {p: 'PhoneCtrl', l: 'LandlineCtrl' }">
  <communicator controller-name="test.p" message="'test1'"></communicator>
  <communicator controller-name="test.l"></communicator>

</div>
  
  
</div>
```

.

**Original (irrelevant now but can help other related issues)**

Yes, it should work.

A test with Angular 1.3:

http://jsfiddle.net/p6Hb4/9/

Things to check:

- Is the controller defined and added to the module? It will not work

  If the controller is just a global function it won't work. It has to be added via the `<myModule>.controller("<controllerName>", <functiion>)` API
- Does `ng-controller` work? Just adding it to the template

  Similarly, does using ng-controller directly outside of the directive work?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Meligy. My problem starts when the controller name is an object value not a plain text. In the example you shared think about the controllers names are coming from the server and I'm passing them to the directive as parameters.

Comment: I think I might have found the problem. Check the update in my answer

Comment: No, Still. See, the directive receive the value correctly and start searching for a controller called "workflowStep.WorkflowTaskType.DataMessageViewViewName" however this is not my controller and him to search for a controller after evaluating the value of this object.
I tried the following

`<bpm-completed-task controllername="{{workflowStep.WorkflowTaskType.DataMessageViewViewName}}" taskdata="workflowStep.WorkflowTaskOutcome.TaskOutcome" type="workflowStep.WorkflowTaskType.DataMessageViewViewName">
        </bpm-completed-task>`
and also it doesn't work

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong again. You need something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762229/dynamic-ng-controller-name  - I have some work now but will return with an example combining both of them

Comment: Thank You. I will be waiting for your contribution.

Comment: Let's hope 3rd time is lucky. Try the current update.

Comment: I liked that. I have other problem, How can I watch on controller-name? :|