# AngularJS - Using NgRoute's params in a controller name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angularjs-routing, ngroute

I have a route set up in AngularJS, with a variable parameter.

This is an extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534710/angularjs-how-to-use-routeparams-in-generating-the-templateurl); I can use `params` in a variable templateUrl like so:

```
.when('/course/:lesson', {
    templateUrl: function(params){
         return '/partials/course/' + params.lesson;
    }
    //...
})
```

However, if I try to do something for a variable controller name I get an `unknown provider` error

```
.when('/course/:lesson', {
    templateUrl: function(params){
         return '/partials/course/' + params.lesson;
    },
    controller: function(params){
         return params.lesson + 'Ctrl';
    }
})
```

Basically, instead of writing 100 different routes which all follow the exact same structure, I want to take whatever the `lesson` variable is and map it to the `/partials/course/{{lesson}}` route as well as the `{{lesson}}Ctrl` controller.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like below, not cleaner one. But it will work

```
controller: function($scope, $controller, $routeParams){
     $controller($routeParams.lesson + 'Ctrl', {$scope: $scope});
}
```

Handling such situation will be easier, if you will look at `ui.router`, which has [**`controllerProvider`**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#controllers) which will work like you were trying.

Comment: This is great, I didn't know you could pass in `$controller` like this!

Answer (score 0):

No - controllers name are static - they are functions, that are compiled before we start our app. More info [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller).

However, it is possible to dynamically add controller to view based of `ngController`. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762229/dynamic-ng-controller-name)

Comment: Controller name is static however you can create you controller instance manually. Check Panraj's answer.