# How to set the ng-controller value from an array in the model?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to set the name of the ng-controller, through looping an array. However, it seems it's not working. This is the code I have so far:

**JS**:

```
var app = angular.module('xmil', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('mainController', ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.tabsArray = [{
            numero: '1',
            ControllerName: 'GeneralController',
            grupo: 'General'
        },
        {
            numero: '2',
            ControllerName: 'ParametrosController',
            grupo: 'CEMS'
        },
        {
            numero: '3',
            ControllerName: 'CilindrosController',
            grupo: 'Cilindros'
        },
        {
            numero: '4',
            ControllerName: 'EquiposController',
            grupo: 'Equipos'
        },
        {
            numero: '5',
            ControllerName: 'DPController',
            grupo: 'DP'
        },
        {
            numero: '6',
            ControllerName: 'MPController',
            grupo: 'MP'
        },
    ];
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="tab in tabsArray">
  <div [ng-controller]={{tab.ControllerName}}></div>
</div>
```

The purpose of this is to make the HTML code smaller.

How can I achieve to set the values of `tab.ControllerName` to the `ng-controller` of each `div` created?

Comment: I don't think that you can use the `[]` syntax in AngularJS. This is an Angular feature.

Comment: Could you please provide me a small example, please?

Comment: did not work with AngularJS myself lately. seems as if you have to create a custom `dynamic-ng-controller`directive for this. maybe this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51307872/4527675